# .htaccess set phtml to be run as php

Tags: .htaccess, php

`AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php5 .php4 .php .php3 .php2 .phtml`

`AddType application/x-httpd-php .php5 .php4 .php .php3 .php2 .phtml`

...within a .htaccess file but my .phtml files are not running as php, they're just showing the code!

Have I missed something?

Comment: No, doesn't that tell the browser what to do with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your server configured to read .htaccess files? To test this simply write random content in it. If the server still works the file is ignored otherwise it returns a 500 Internal Server Error.

To enable .hhtaccess file support in your configuration use the [AllowOverride](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/core.html#allowoverride) directive.

Comment: Stupid server doesnt support htaccess :(. Wish my clients knew what they were doing.

Comment: my server recognizes the .htaccess file , but this configuration isnt working for me :(

Forbidden
You do not have permission to access this document.